# Is there an easy way to make GORM errors restful api friendly

Tags: json, parsing, grails, grails-orm

I'm working on a simple Restful API in GRAILS, I want users to be able to create an entry on one of my domain classes, so they can hit an entry point /rest/v1/create/event?params

In the receiving controller if the GORM entry fails, !event.save()

I have code like this:

```
def result = [
    'status'    :   'error',
    'data'      :   event.errors.fieldErrors.toList()
]
render result as JSON
```

Is there a way to easily make event.errors.fieldErrors JSON friendly, something with just the field error and message, or will I have to write a parser method to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ending up writing a short method to parse through and make friendly errors

If anyone finds this useful, here it is:

```
def gorm_errors(results) {
        results =  results.fieldErrors.toList()
        def errors = []
        for(error in results) {
            errors.add([
                'type' : 'invalid_entry', 
                'field' : error.field, 
                'rejected_value' : error.rejectedValue, 
                'message' : error.defaultMessage
            ])
        }
        return errors
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more "groovy-er" version of the above example:

```
def gorm_errors(errors) {
    errors.fieldErrors.toList().collect {error ->
        [
            'type': 'invalid_entry', 
            'field': error.field, 
            'rejected_value': error.rejectedValue, 
            'message': error.defaultMessage
        ]
}
```